# When should smart pointers be used to hold arrays?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've see many answers that suggest using smart pointers to hold dynamically-allocated arrays in memory. My view has always been that if the size is known it should be wrapped in an `std::array`, and likewise if the size wasn't known (i.e. by making the pointer type of the smart pointer an array of unknown bound and `reset()`'ing it later on) one should use `std::vector`. And indeed that is what I always do.

For example, recently I saw an answer that used `std::unique_ptr<int[5]> p(new int[5])`. This seems analogous to constructing an `std::array<int, 5>` since the size is known. Moreover, the added benefits are that `std::array` statically-allocates its array and contains array-like features like the size, iterators, and more.

So what are the reasons for using a smart pointer to hold an array over using other standard containers made specifically for that purpose?

Comment: Not `unique_ptr`, but `shared_ptr<int[N]>` could be useful for implementing a reference-counted array.

Comment: Don't look at the smart pointers as just self-deleting pointers, look at them in terms of ownership.

Comment: Good point, but then what's the difference between that and holding an `std::array` in a smart pointer (other than one less level of indirection)?

Comment: Another question is why they used `unique_ptr<int[5]>` instead of `unique_ptr<int[]>`  The latter IS useful, unlike `std::array` it can accommodate an array whose size isn't known at compile time, and it doesn't invite people to try expensive size-changing operations like `std::vector` can do.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<int[5]> p(new int[5])` shouldn't even compile, you're passing an `int*` where the constructor expects a pointer to an array of size 5.

Comment: Sometimes you really do want a pointer since the collection has to hold objects of different types and you want to avoid slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `unique_ptr<T[]>` does not require a static size- it can be just `unique_ptr<int[]>`.

> Moreover, the added benefits are that std::array statically-allocates
>   its array

This is not strictly guaranteed to be a *benefit*. Consider if I have a 10-megabyte array- that's going to blow my stack.

Generally speaking, people choose this approach when they want the array size to be fixed on creation, but be able to mutate the members. Note that for `std::vector`, you can only make *both* the elements *and* the `vector` `const`, or neither. You cannot make only the vector but not the elements `const`.

Comment: Mm, I suppose that's a good point: a dynamically-allocated, automatically-managed, fixed-size mutable array. Still, is that really _so_ useful?

Comment: No idea, I don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `std::array` is a static array.  If you declare a `std::array<int, 5>` on the stack, the actual array is on the stack.  Whereas `std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[5])` puts the actual array on the heap instead.  That might not seem like a big difference for small arrays, but it is a big deal for large arrays.  Just because an array is fixed length does not mean it should always be on the stack.  It depends on the size of the array and how much stack space is available.  Putting a large array on the stack risks throwing a stack overflow error.  Putting a large array on the heap will not throw that (unless the stack is already full so the `unique_ptr` cannot be constructed after the array is allocated), though it does have a lesser risk of throwing an out of memory error if the heap/memmgr is full, but that would happen before the `Unique_ptr` is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a unique pointer to an array when you know the time at runtime but it won't change, this guarantees that you will allocate space for just those objects and no more. With a vector you could be allocating more space internally, it is implementation-defined, but in order to have good amortized times for inserting, it usually allocates at least double of what it needs each time it grows the vector, since it needs copying.

Comment: _"it is implementation-defined, but in order to have good amortized times for inserting, it usually allocates at least double of what it needs each time it grows the vector"_ No, not really. If you reserve a specific quantity you can generally expect pretty much that amount of space to be reserved. There will be no growing or copying if the size doesn't change.

Comment: Well, that is true most of the time but it is still implementation-defined. If you want guarantees, you should stick to unique_ptr in this very case.

Comment: Meh suppose so. Seems pretty weak but I get it

Answer (score 0):

The tradeoff between `std::vector` and `std::array` is a simple one: "is the size always the same?".

Then the decision "do I want a smart pointer or not" is the same for any other type. Do I want to pass it around as a shared object? Use `std::shared_ptr`. Do I want to pass around one large object, without making copies? Use `std::unique_ptr`.

Let's say you have one 2048 buffer that you want to pass around in your program, but not introduce many copies. You could use `std::shared_ptr<std::array<unsigned char, 2048>>` for that.

Comment: You haven't addressed the overlap where `std::unique_ptr<int[5]>` is used for no apparent reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Indirectly I have. If you consider `int[5]` a large object for your particular architecture and it's being passed around (I have no way of knowing - there is no link to the code), then it could very well be a valid reason.

Comment: I don't see how? You can pass a vector by reference, or by move.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But a vector is not statically sized.

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot, I don't want to accidently `push_back` into an array all other code assumes to be 2048 elements.

Comment: So, basically, what Puppy said? Suppose. Perhaps you could actually write this into your answer as you only indirectly imply it.

Answer (score 0):

The smart pointers for arrays are just that - smart pointers. Therefore you should use them where smart pointer usage is appropriate.

### Interacting with legacy code

Suppose you have legacy codebase with a function that creates an array which you have to `delete[]` later. How will you make this code exception-safe? Simple, store it in the smart pointer.

```
stuff* legacy_function();
// ...
std::unique_ptr<stuff[]> arr(legacy_function());
```

Similar scenario: legacy function wants ownership of the array:

```
std::unique_ptr<stuff[]> arr(new stuff[20]);
// do operations, possibly exception-throwing
other_legacy_function(arr.release());
```

Try doing *that* with `std::vector`!

While the proper solution is to change your design, there might be social and practical reasons why you won't do it (third-party code?). Or, maybe you're refactoring code step-by-step?

### Implementing containers

There is no reason containers couldn't be implemented on top of `std::unique_ptr`. I see no reason why somebody writing hand-made containers couldn't benefit from existing "policy-handlers" instead of writing code manually to satisfy Rule Of Three/Five.

### Summary

Yes, you should prefer containers. Yes, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` isn't *that* useful.